# What is a better way of saying "I am in right way?"

Tags: expressions, measure-expressions

I am in group conversation and I want say if I'm on the right track. If I'm going in this "direction", I will have a good results. Which can be the expression that resumes this thought?

"I am in right way?"

Note: My English level is medium, please tell me if the my phrases is good or bad (e.g. 2 on 1 to 10)

Comment: The question reads like you trying to say, "I am on the right track."

Comment: Ok, but if I want construct a question I should say " Am I on the right track?" Am I sure?

Comment: Nice one, mate!

Answer (score 3):

> on the right track
>
> definition:
>
> 1.acting or thinking in a way that is likely to result in success

Following this context, if you were on the *wrong* track, you would be heading toward failure.

The saying applies to *any* situation that ends in a:

- Destination (walking to, driving to, following directions to)
- Result (test/exam, sport, group effort)
- Object/Goal (flirting, making plans, seeking employment)

In terms of usage, it is appropriate after being *sidetracked*:

> SIDETRACK
>
> verb
>
> 1.cause (someone) to be distracted from an immediate or important issue

As to your level of English proficiency, I rate it a solid 4.5, which is clearly on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

> Am I heading in the right direction?

This is idiomatic, meaning your activity or thought process is proceeding (heading) the way you or others want (the direction leading to a positive outcome).

Comment: But this expression don't should use when I will drive, for example?

Comment: Literally yes. But this is idiomatic meaning your activity or thought process is proceeding the way you or others want (a positive outcome). Please check my edit.